# div width is too large in Explorer and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a div called "wrapper" which contains input fields. In Firefox everything looks good but if I run my code in Explorer and Chrome the width of my wrapper is too large and its position jumps to the right.
Here is my css code:

```
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

#type { 

    padding: 5px; 
    border: 0.5px solid LightGray; 
    width: 250px;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

#address, #lng, #lat {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 0.5px solid LightGray;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}


label {
    color: #707070;
}

 #wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: rigth;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0.95;
  }
```

and here is my html file.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <input id="input-id" type="file" class="file-loading" multiple>         
    <br/>
    <select id="type" title="Select Map Version" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
         <option value="all">All Map Versions</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <label for="adress">Adresse:</label><input id="address" type="textbox"></input><br/><br/>   
    <input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="search"><br/><br/>

    <label for="Long">Longitude:</label><input id="lng" type="textbox"></input><br/>
    <label for="Lat">Latitude:</label><input id="lat" type="textbox"></input><br/><br/>
    <input id="submit2" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="search"><br/><br/>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should works well if you remove the `</input>`s. Run the snippet below:. I run it both in FF and Chrome, the form fields are shown on the left.

```css
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

#type { 

    padding: 5px; 
    border: 0.5px solid LightGray; 
    width: 250px;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

#address, #lng, #lat {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 0.5px solid LightGray;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}


label {
    color: #707070;
}

 #wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: rigth;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0.95;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <input id="input-id" type="file" class="file-loading" multiple>         
    <br/>
    <select id="type" title="Select Map Version" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
         <option value="all">All Map Versions</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <label for="adress">Adresse:</label><input id="address" type="textbox"><br/><br/>   
    <input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="search"><br/><br/>

    <label for="Long">Longitude:</label><input id="lng" type="textbox"><br/>
    <label for="Lat">Latitude:</label><input id="lat" type="textbox"><br/><br/>
    <input id="submit2" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="search"><br/><br/>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` in your CSS.